# How to combine all css and js in to single request in mediawiki?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I am developing an application by mediawiki. For every page 18 js and 17 css http requests are sent.

I have also tried load.php to combine into single request. But load.php does not work properly.

Is there any other way to combine all (css and js) files into single request ?

Comment: you can distribute any scripts/css to open when a user enters a particular block, example `<?php if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index.php')){ ?> //show this scripts/css only if someone get to index
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/some_for_index.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/index.css" type="text/css" /> 
<?php } if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'member.php')){ ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/some_for_member.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/css_for_member.css" type="text/css" /> 
<? } ?>`

Comment: thanks for the reply i will do it

Answer (score 1):

You need to use mediawiki's ResouceLoader to achieve this. You can define a module that combines a set of js and css files and optional dependencies to other modules. https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/ResourceLoader has further information